# How do I define a variable from another function?

Tags: matlab

I have a multi-fuction script that is supposed to ask the user for 4 different cars and weigh them based on ratings to give the user the best car to purchase.
What I want to do is have a prompt for every car the user inputs so the user can put in data for each variable the user decides to use. However, when titling the prompt I want to use the cars name in the prompt. It seems impossible to me and Im not sure what to do, im very new to coding.

---

### Main Script

```
prompt1 = {'How Many Cars (4): '};
title1 = 'Cars';
answer1 = inputdlg(prompt1, title1, [1 40]);

Q1 = str2double(answer1{1});

[N] = Group_Function1(Q1);

Car1 = N(1);       %Stores the names of the cars
Car2 = N(2);
Car3 = N(3);
Car4 = N(4);

prompt2 = {'How Many Variables (4): '};
title2 = 'Variables';
answer2 = inputdlg(prompt2, title2, [1 50]);

fprintf('This code can accept costs between 0-100000\n');
fprintf('This code can accept top speeds between 0-200\n');
fprintf('This code can also accept the terms none, some, & alot\n');
fprintf('This code can accept safety ratings between 0-5\n');

Q2 = str2double(answer2{1});

[V,W] = Group_Function2(Q2);

W1 = W(1);       %Stores the weights of the varibles
W2 = W(2);
W3 = W(3);
W4 = W(4);

for h=1:Q1
[H] = Group_Function3(V);
Weights(h,:)=H;
end
```

---

### Group_Function1

```
function [N] = Group_Function1(Q1)
for Q = 1:Q1
prompt = {'Name of Car:'};
title = 'Car Name';          
answer = inputdlg(prompt,title, [1 80])'; 
N(Q) = answer(1);
end
```

---

### Group_Function2

```
function [V,W] = Group_Function2(Q2)

for Q=1:Q2
prompt = {'Variable? (Negative Variables First):','weights in decimal 
form?'};
title = 'Variables and Weights';          
answer = inputdlg(prompt,title, [1 80])';    
V(Q)=answer(1);
W(Q)=str2double(answer{2});
s=sum(W);
end
if s~=1
    fprintf('Weights do not add up to 1. Try Again!\n');
    Group_Function2(Q2);
end
end
```

---

### Group_Function3 (Where the problem occurs)

```
function [H] = Group_Function3(V)
prompt = {V};
title = ['Variable Ratings For' Group_Function1(answer{1})];
h = inputdlg(prompt, title, [1 80])';
end
```

---

### The Problem

For 'Group_Function3' I want the prompt to include the users inputs from 'Group_Function1' so that when the prompt comes up to input the answers I know which vehicle I am entering for.

Answer (score 1):

Each `function` runs in its own workspace, it means it does not know the state or content of variables outside of it. If you want a function to know something specific (like the name of a car), you have to give that to the function in the input parameters. A function can have several inputs parameters, you are not limited to only one.

Before going into the `Group_Function3` , I'd like to propose a new way for `Group_Function1`.

---

**Group_Function1 :**

You run a loop to ask independantly for each car name. It is rather tedious to have to validate each dialog boxe. Here is a way to ask for the 4 car names in one go:

replace the beginning of your script with:

```
title1  = 'Cars';
prompt1 = {'How Many Cars (4): '};
answer1 = inputdlg(prompt1, title1 );

nCars   = str2double( answer1{1} );

CarNames = getCarNames(nCars) ; % <= use this function
% [N] = Group_Function1(Q1);    % instead of this one
```

and replace `Group_Function1` with:

```
function CarNames = getCarNames(nCars)
    title = 'Car Names';          
    prompt = cellstr( [repmat('Name of car #',nCars,1) , sprintf('%d',(1:nCars)).'] ) ;
    CarNames = inputdlg( prompt, title, [1 80] ) ; 
end
```

Now `CarNames` is a cell array containing the name of your 4 cars (as your variable `N` was doing earlier. I recommend sligthly more explicit variable names).

You can run the rest of your code as is (just replace `N` with `CarNames`, and `Q1` with `nCars`).

---

**Group_Function3 :**

when you get to the `Group_Function3`, you have to send the current car name to the function (so it can use the name in the title or prompt). So replace your `Group_Function3` as following (we add an input variable to the function definition):

```
function H = Group_Function3( V , thisCarName )
    prompt = {V};
    title = ['Variable Ratings For' thisCarName];
    H = inputdlg(prompt, title, [1 80])';
end
```

and in your main script, call it that way:

```
for h = 1:nCars
    thisCarName = carNames{h} ;
    H = Group_Function3( V , thisCarName ) ;
    % ...
    % anything else you want to do in this loop
end
```